# Keep leading 0 in date calculation

Tags: php

I want to get the last month/year based on this month/year, so I'm using the php code/calculation:

```
<?php
$this_month = date("m");
$this_year = date("Y");
if($this_month == "01"){
$history_month = "12";
$history_year = $this_year - 1;
}
else{
$history_month = $this_month - 1;
$history_year = $this_year;
}
$history_var = $history_year."".$history_month;
?>
```

Problem is, when I echo out `history_var` I see `20188` **instead of** `201808`.

How do I keep the leading `0` on `08`?

Alternatively, is there a simpler way to calculate last month?

Comment: according to php manual "m is a Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros  like 01 through 12"

Comment: @Sfili_81 Yes I know, but the calculation is removing the 0, which I don't want to happen!

Comment: You're subtracting 1 from the month, which will convert the string to an int and drop it the leading 0.

Comment: You cannot "keep" a leading 0 while doing integer math. You need to convert the result back to a string and prepend a `"0"` character.

Comment: You could try sprintf("%02d", $this_month);

Comment: @aynber There is no casting-to-hex involved here. A leading 0 only matters when *parsing* an integer literal, not when casting strings to integers at runtime.

Comment: @meagar I've removed that part of my comment after I tested it.

Comment: Thanks @meagar - Any ideas why Abderrahim's answer got a downvote? It seems to work fine?

Comment: @W.H. I've no idea, the downvoter is welcome (but not required) to offer an explanation.

Comment: @meagar - I get that, but it makes it confusing. So is it something that you would personally recommend using? Or is there a simpler way than that, or even the way I originally coded?

Comment: a shorter Version would be: `$d = (new DateTime())->sub(new DateInterval("P1M"));` - then use that DateTime-Object to output your desired format: `echo $d->format("Ym");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this  :

Test if `$history_month` less then 10 -> add Zero

```
 <?php
    $this_month = date("m");
    $this_year = date("Y");
    if($this_month == "01"){
    $history_month = "12";
    $history_year = $this_year - 1;
    }
    else{
    $history_month = $this_month - 1;
    $history_year = $this_year;
    }

    $history_month = $history_month >= 10 ? $history_month : "0".$history_month;

    $history_var = $history_year."".$history_month;
    ?>
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted as it does work. Although, I did edit this to the simpler form of `if($history_month < 10){$history_month = "0".$history_month;}`

Comment: it's down voted because some one marked you question as duplicate. Enjoy

Comment: I meant your answer was down voted!